# Parametrization generated by a cycloid of a unit circle

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Given a parametric equation of a cycloid ($t \in [0,2\pi])$:

$x(t)=(t−\sin t);y(t)=(1−\cos t)$.

Together with the line segment from the origin to $2\pi$. ([Cycloid Image and problem definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbaZm.jpg); 0).

Find the line integral of the vector field $F =\langle x^2,\frac{x}{2}\rangle$ on the curve oriented
counterclockwise.

---

I have tried to take the derivative of the $r(t)$ and also have taken the dot product of $F(r(t)) \cdot r'(t)$ , but I cannot get the answer. I have tried Green's Theorem and wasn't successful. I need to understand this, your help is sincerely appreciated.

Comment: Possibly your problem is that your curve description does not quite correspond to the curve you need to be integrating around. The curve of integration starts by going from $(0,0)$ to $(2\pi, 0)$ along the $x$-axis. But then it follows the cycloid *in the reverse direction of the parametrization* to get back to the origin.

Comment: Paul, by using the regular method of integrating 

$ \int F(r(t)).r'(t)dt$

I could not get the answer. I think the image says the area is 3$pi$ 
I am thinking , since we know the area under the curve, should we just divide it by 2.

Because after using Greens theorem, we get $d/dx(x/2) = 1/2$

Then we can use the formula $1/2\int dA $

Please correct me if I am wrong. I am not sure how I can get this done algebraically or using formulas.
We can conclude it is $3\pi/2$ , please verify this for me.

Comment: Since $\frac {\partial F_x}{\partial y} = 0$, that is indeed the content of Green' theorem, so that should be the answer.